# Why is my ejs outputting the actual html code and not rendering it as html?

Tags: node.js, express, bootstrap-4, ejs, template-engine

I am doing some simple validation on a form and using bootstrap for alert dismissing. I have an ejs partial for displaying error messages. When trying to render the error message its just showing the actual block of code.

Here is my partials ejs:

```
<% if(typeof errors != 'undefined') { %>
    <% errors.forEach(error => { %>
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <%= error.msg %>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
  <%  }) %>
<% } %>
```

Here is where I include that partial to the register.ejs file I have

```
<%= include ("./partials/messages") %>
        <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input
              type="name"
              id="name"
              name="name"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter Name"
              value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined' ? name : '' %>"
            />
```

Here is a screenshot of what it is outputting:
[image]

Why is it showing the actual code instead of rendering as HTML?

Comment: Shouldn't include use `-` instead of `=`? `<%- include("./partials/messages") %>`. The docs say: "You'll likely want to use the raw output tag (`<%-`) with your include to avoid double-escaping the HTML output."

Comment: This was the issue, thank you!